# Can I make a somewhat dynamic yes/no dropdown based on JSON file data?

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON file that will be full of user information and in the admin page displaying all of the users I want a column for "Is Admin?" with a yes/no dropdown list. Can I make the list show Yes and have No as the other for admins and show No and have Yes as the other option for non-admins? The page is vanilla JavaScript as I'm still pretty new at this.

A sample of the user data is

```json
{"id":"2",
"username":"david",
"password":"1234",
"user_id":"127",
"date":"2022-02-14 23:45:37",
"is_admin":"1"}
```

As simple as it is, the JavaScript to display the page is

```
function loadData(data) {
    
       let table = document.querySelector("#user-list");
       
       for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
           
           let row = `<tr>
           <td>${data[i].user_id} </td>
           <td>${data[i].username}  </td>
           <td>${data[i].date} </td>
           <td>${data[i].is_admin == 1 ? "Yes" : "No"}  </td>
           </tr>
           `;
           
           table.innerHTML += row;
           
       }

}
```

[added screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYwG1.png)

The Admins yes/no should be

```html
<select>
<option>Yes</option>
<option>No</option>
</select>
```

And the non admins should be

```html
<select>
<option>No</option>
<option>Yes</option>
</option>
```

Also just realized the column names are wrong, but the Admin column is correct, other than not being a dropdown.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the problem correctly but, for what I understood, you are trying to show a value which is different from the real one (the one in the json). If that's the problem then you could simply add another column to your json entries differentiating the real value from the one you want to show (say is_Admin and vis_is_Admin

Comment: Sorry, i'll try to add a screenshot of a rough draft of the basic table layout. in the image one user is an admin and one isn't. For the one that is an admin, I would want their dropdown to automatically be Yes but with the option to change to no, while the one who isn't an admin, theirs should be No with the option to change to yes. Then ultimately there will be a button to submit the updated info back to the server but that's unrelated to this. Off to try to add a screenshot.

Comment: For boolean properties (YES/NO), `<input type="checkbox">` should be used, not `<select>`.

Comment: One thing I had considered was in the Admin column, if you're admin there's nothing or a "Remove Admin" button and for non-admins having a "Make Admin" button and forgoing the <select> altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of doing it:

```js
const data=[{"id":"1",
"username":"Harry",
"password":"5678",
"user_id":"112",
"date":"2022-02-11 13:45:37",
"is_admin":"0"},
{"id":"2",
"username":"david",
"password":"1234",
"user_id":"127",
"date":"2022-02-04 11:05:47",
"is_admin":"1"},
{"id":"3",
"username":"Molly",
"password":"9834",
"user_id":"187",
"date":"2022-01-21 08:15:00",
"is_admin":"0"}];

function loadData(data) {
document.querySelector("#user-list").innerHTML=data.map(d=>`<tr>
  <td>${d.user_id}</td>
  <td>${d.username}  </td>
  <td>${d.date} </td>
  <td><select><option value="1"${d.is_admin==1?" selected":""}>yes</option><option value="0"${d.is_admin==0?" selected":""}>no</option></select></td></tr>`).join("");
}

loadData(data);
```

```html
<table>
<thead><tr><th>id</th><th>name</th><th>date</th><th>admin</th></tr>
<tbody id="user-list"></tbody></table>
```

The callback function in the `.map()` call builds an HTML string for a `<tr>` element with all its content for each of the objects contained in the `data`-array. These individual HTML strings are the elements of the returned array and they are `join("")`-ed together at the end to become a single HTML string again.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't considered using map. I don't quite understand the code so I'll take some time to dig in to that and see exactly what it means and what I can't grasp. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why not make the `value` of the `option`s be 1 and 0 so that no translation has to be done on submission? Not that there's any discussion of submission in the OP...

Comment: That's something else I hadn't considered. That would make sense for when I update the database. Thank you for pointing this out. It makes me feel dumb but it definitely helps me figure out the things I need to be thinking about when writing code.

Comment: Ok, if I'm understanding this right, this makes a select that's always yes no but if is_admin is false, No is selected. But I'm stuck on the join, what is that for?

Comment: I was afk until now. `.map()` starts a loop over all elements of an array and returns a new array with whatever the callback function returns for each element. In this case it reruns HTML strings for `<option>` elements.

Comment: Thank you for going into more detail. I understand using map to create a new array but I don't understand why you used a join at the end. Could you please clarify this for me so I can understand better? Thank you kindly.

Comment: My previous comment was not entirely correct: not the `<option>` but `<tr>` elements are returned as HTML strings. I put an explanation in my post now, including the `join()` part.

Comment: Thanks again! so the join is essentially to print out one long string for the html. In my mind it was creating an html string for each element and just showing each element. But I guess that's not how it actually works. Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: It is always worth your time, creating one long HTML string instead of doing multiple `DOMElement.innerHTML+=...` as each assignment to `.innerHTML` is fairly time consuming (it involves parsing and creating DOM elements).

Comment: I never thought about it like that before but it totally makes sense. I haven't made it far enough in skill level to have spent much time worried about optimizing performance. Thank you again for your help.