# Can I make different buttons based on json boolean value?

Tags: javascript, html

Recently I asked about a dropdown with dynamic options based on the boolean value of a json property, and I got help and I absolute appreciate that. Over the course of that discussion I had a different idea to test but I'm having trouble implementing it.

an example of the users in the json file is

```
{"id":"2",
"username":"david",
"password":"1234",
"user_id":"127",
"date":"2022-02-14 23:45:37",
"is_admin":"1"}
```

the current javascript that loads a static table is

```
let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    let row = `
     <tr>
<td>${data[i].username}</td>
<td>${data[i].password}</td>
<td>${data[i].user_id}</td>
<td>${data[i].is_admin == 1 ? "Yes" : "No"}</td>
     </tr>
    `;

    table.innerHTML += row;
}
```

It works, it makes the table and everything is good but in that last td I basically an trying

```
if(is_admin == true) {

make remove admin button
 
}else if (is_admin == false) {

make make admin button

}
```

but I'm struggling with how to do this. I've tried creating the button and appending it to the td but I get an error saying td is null, which I also don't understand. Do I need to do something different to append things to elements that were dynamically created?

I'm mostly just looking for a point in the right direction to try to work through this on my own. All of this is in vanilla javascript, if it matters. I have no experience using any frameworks yet.

[Can I make a somewhat dynamic yes/no dropdown based on JSON file data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71189505/8634022) is a link to my previous question if there's any relevant information contained in it. Thank you very much.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to put a `<button>` instead of the strings `"Yes"` and `"No"`, is that correct?  The code is already conditionally creating those strings based on the value of the `is_admin` field.  What stops you from using that same logic?  If you've made an attempt to do exactly that and it's not working in some way, where is that attempt?

Comment: Yes, I want buttons in lieu of strings. Honestly I didn't even know you could put that sort of thing inside a ternary operator. The ragged attempts at getting it to work ended up in the recycle bin, I got so frustrated last night I deleted the page and started over.

Comment: Any expression can go in the ternary conditional operator.  All you're dealing with here are strings (which contain HTML, but they're still just strings to JavaScript).

Comment: Thats very interesting, I had no idea. Thank you very much for pointing that out!

Comment: Based on your suggestion, created the buttons in the ternary operator and it worked like a charm. They're not functional yet but now that they're in the page, that shouldn't be an issue. Thank you for your suggestion. I really have to stop overthinking things.